# How do you say "I am americanized" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I am not sure if this sentence is right but here it goes:

> Ich bin amerikanisiert.

Is grammatically correct? Would this be used in common speech?

Comment: Please provide some context.

Comment: Ich wohne schon seit mehr als 20 Jahren in Amerika, also bin ich amerikanisiert

Comment: I consider it as extremely unusual to use “amerikanisiert” for a person.

Comment: How do i say ' i am americanised' ? I googled it and found nothing.

Comment: I would say something like *Er/Sie ist geprägt vom amerikanischen Lebensstil.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "Ich bin amerikanisiert" you convey a deliberate exaggeration and you would only use it in colloquial language as in "Nach zwei Wochen in Kalifornien war ich schon amerikanisiert".

You might stress such exaggerations with an additionan "buchstäblich" ("literally"). Or even more colloquial: "Nach zwei Wochen in Kalifornien war ich schon *voll* amerikanisiert".

Answer (score 3):

> Ich bin amerikanisiert.

...is not dreadful, but quite unusual. Grammatically, it is correct. Consider [this article on Wikipedia (de) on Americanisation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerikanisierung), which refers to e.g. names being Americanised, but not, generally, people.